# How to update access database from textbox input in c#

Tags: c#, database, ms-access

I am trying to update my database by selecting a specific record from the database and displaying it in the text boxes, and then clicking a button to update the edit from the text box input.
However, when I try to check if record exists in database by getting the count of number of rows affected, it always comes up as 0.
Could someone help me figure out why this is?

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string ghost1 = textBox1.Text.ToString();
            string ghost2 = textBox2.Text.ToString();
            string ghost3 = textBox3.Text.ToString();
            string ghost4 = textBox4.Text.ToString();

            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\jameschoi\Desktop\andrew.mdb";
            conn.Open();
            //OleDbDataReader myReader = null;
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Stock WHERE SKU ='" + ghost1 + "'", conn);
            OleDbCommand combank = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Stock (Description, Qty, Price) VALUES ('" + ghost2 + "', '" + ghost3 + "', '" + ghost4 + "')", conn);

            int frango = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            string test1 = frango.ToString();

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            try
            {
                if (frango > 0)
                {
                    combank.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    MessageBox.Show("Update Successful");
                    conn.Close();
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Record does not exist");
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Failed due to" + ex.Message);
            }

            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
                DataSet_update();
            }

        }
```

Comment: just to be sure, what does `SELECT * FROM Stock WHERE SKU ='" + ghost1 + "'` looked like before you call `ExecuteNonQuery()`? a simple whitespace can ruin everything..

Comment: Always use SQL Parameters rather than gluing your SQL together.  Among other things, you are passing what I presume are numbers (Qty, Price) as text.  Also, the Text property is `string` to start with - `ToString()` is pointless

Comment: @BagusTesa I don't understand what you mean? If you mean the spaces between the `+ ghost1 +` , I've tried `+ghost1+` and frango still comes up at 0.

Comment: @Icecubelegacy, no i don't mean `+ ghost1 +` or `+ghost1+` but the string `command` itself, how does it looked like? try to throw a dump it somewhere, so we can inspect the generated query.. it is a possibility that `ghost1="someId"` or `ghost1="someId "` or it might be the `command="SELECT * FROM Stock WHERE SKU ='string@b473620'`, we can't be sure.. Plutonix is right, concatenate strings to make database query is a bad idea, use something like [entity framework](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/tree/master/src) or something.

Comment: @BagusTesa Thanks, sorry I'm very new to coding ^^ . I'll try that now.

Comment: @Plutonix Thanks~

Comment: @Icecubelegacy, it's ok, just to be sure to check things thoroughly and if possible use *Debug* feature in Visual Studio and put some breakpoints. [Here some reading material](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/79508/Mastering-Debugging-in-Visual-Studio-A-Beginn) -- i'm still learning too though..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find it more easier like

```
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Stock WHERE SKU ='" + ghost1 + "'", conn);
int rowCount = (int) command.ExecuteScalar();
if(rowCount > 0)
{
    OleDbCommand combank = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Stock (Description, Qty, Price) VALUES ('" + ghost2 + "', '" + ghost3 + "', '" + ghost4 + "')", conn);
    combank.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show("Update Successful");
}
```

But this code is not recommended as it is prone to SQL Injection. You Should use `Using` and `Parameterized Queries` like this

```
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(/* connection info */))
{
    sqlq = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Stock WHERE SKU = ?"
    conn.Open();
    using (OleDbCommand comm1 = new OleDbCommand(sqlq, conn))
    {
        OleDbParameter ghost1Param  = new OleDbParameter();
        comm1.Parameters.Add(ghost1Param).Value = ghost1;
        int rowCount = (int) comm1.ExecuteScalar();
        if(rowCount > 0)
        {
            sqlaq = "INSERT INTO Stock (Description, Qty, Price) VALUES (?, ?, ?)"
            using (OleDbCommand combank = new OleDbCommand(sqlaq, conn))
            {
                combank.Parameters.Add(ghost2Param).Value = ghost2;
                combank.Parameters.Add(ghost3Param).Value = ghost3;
                combank.Parameters.Add(ghost4Param).Value = ghost4;
                combank.ExecuteNonQuery();
                //Update signifies Alteration to exsisting record.
                MessageBox.Show("Insert was Successful"); //Try to use relevant messages
            }
        }
    }
}
```

OleDbCommand and OdbCommand does not support named parameters and uses the ? placeholder instead, so the order of the parameters is important. However, you can give names to its parameters instead of using ?, for readability purposes.

you should use 'using' when you want to be sure an object that allocates resources will be cleaned up. Because if 'using' keyword around where you create new object, will ensures Dispose will be called on it for you. It guarantees that Dispose will be called whatever happens... even if there is an exception thrown within the body of the using statement.

Comment: I just changed my code to fit yours with the parameters and `using` statements, however there is an error saying "Index or primary key cannot contain a null value" at `combank.ExecuteNonQuery();`

Comment: Okay the problem is solved now. I just changed the combank command from `INSERT INTO` to `UPDATE Stock SET etc etc etc` and it works now. Thanks for all your help!!