# How to Close OleDB Connection So That I can Delet Excel Data using EPPlus

Tags: c#, excel

I have some problem here when deleting excel data after inserting data using oledb. Error said that my file is being used by another process. I have closed the connection but error still exist. Can anyone help me to solve that problem ?

```
string tampungsementara = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\Proyek Alfon\JadwalPengisianATM\Tampung Data Sementara.xlsx;Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 xml;HDR=YES';";


    private void MoveToScheduleBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
                bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(PindahKeJadwalIsiBW_DoWork);
                bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(PindahKeJadwalIsiBW_RunWorkerCompleted);

                try
                {
                    bw.RunWorkerAsync();
                }
                catch
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("File gagal dipindah !");
                }
            }

    private void PindahKeJadwalIsiBW_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow item in ReviewGV.Rows)
        {
            if (Convert.ToBoolean(item.Cells[0].Value) == true) 
            {
                using (OleDbConnection kon = new OleDbConnection(tampungsementara))
                {
                    string com = "INSERT INTO [Schedule$] ([WSID], [Lokasi]) VALUES (wsid, lokasi)";
                    kon.Open();

                    using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(com, kon))
                    {
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("wsid", item.Cells[1].Value);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("lokasi", item.Cells[2].Value);

                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        kon.Close();
                        //command.Dispose();

                    }
                }

                using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(filetampungsementara))) //error here
                {
                    ExcelWorksheet unsche = package.Workbook.Worksheets["Unschedule"];
                    int h = unsche.Dimension.End.Row;
                    textBox1.Text = h.ToString();
                }
            }
        }
    }

private void PindahKeJadwalIsiBW_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Data berhasil dipindah ke Jadwal Pengisian !");

            TampilJadwal();
            TampilDataLain();
        }
```

Comment: you should use ['using' when you want to be sure an object that allocates resources will be cleaned up](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41338403/3796048). Because if 'using' keyword around where you create new object, will ensures Dispose will be called on it for you. It guarantees that Dispose will be called whatever happens... even if there is an exception thrown within the body of the using statement.

Comment: I have edited my code like above but error still exist. Can you help me to solve that problem ?